# Filter cached DB queries from Rails' logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to filter out DB queries that hit Rails' query cache from Rails logs? The presence of these "queries" makes it harder to debug performance issues

Answer (score 1):

I was going to ask this question a few weeks ago, but then didn't get round to it.  I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, but I'd think doing something like

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = QuietLogger.new

class QuietLogger < Logger
  def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
    super unless message ~= /CACHE/
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this, but what you'd need to do is override the add method on the Logger and check for messages that contain CACHE.  Hopefully I'm not that far off!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [request-log-analyzer](http://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer) for analyzing rails performance from logs.